# Why is a bean resolved with `spring-boot:run` but not `java -jar`?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a  multi-module maven project with @Beans defined here and there.

`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {...})` is configured so that all configuration files and components are scanned.

Application starts successfully from STS and with `mvn spring-boot:run` but crashes when running `java -jar my-module/target/my-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` with:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.c4_soft.lifix.web.FaultController required a bean of type 'com.c4_soft.lifix.common.storage.StorageService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.c4_soft.lifix.common.storage.StorageService' in your configuration.
```

Why are `@Bean` from `common-storage` (among which stands `StorageService`implementation) resolved with `spring-boot:run` and not in packaged application ?

P.S.
I intend to build and run native image. Here is the pom for a "runnable" module

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifix-api-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.lifix</groupId>
    <artifactId>faults-endpoints</artifactId>
    <name>faults-endpoints</name>
    <description>REST endpoints for little fixes app</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-addons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.lifix</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifix-domain</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.lifix</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifix-persistence</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <classifier>${repackage.classifier}</classifier>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                    <jvmArguments>-Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiDocsUrl>https://localhost:4443/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                    <outputFileName>faults-openapi.json</outputFileName>
                    <outputDir>../..</outputDir>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <properties>
                <repackage.classifier>exec</repackage.classifier>
                <native-buildtools.version>0.9.1</native-buildtools.version>
            </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-platform-native</artifactId>
                    <version>${native-buildtools.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${native-buildtools.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

edit : pom after I followed [this sample](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/tree/main/samples/multi-modules) (with no success):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifix-api-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.lifix</groupId>
    <artifactId>faults-endpoints</artifactId>
    <name>faults-endpoints</name>
    <description>REST endpoints for little fixes app</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-addons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-storage</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.lifix</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifix-domain</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.c4-soft.lifix</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifix-persistence</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-image</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-image</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>
                                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                        </exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                    <image>
                                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                                        <env>
                                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                                        </env>
                                        <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                                    </image>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: Check if you jar contains the class mentioned in the error log.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't. Any idea why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: @samabcde not really. They use quite different plugins and don't have much choice as I intend to build a native image. I tried to stick to what I found there https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-native/tree/main/samples/multi-modules but get same error

Comment: FYI, I just tried to download a project in https://start.spring.io/ with spring web, then run `mvn clean install`. Then inside the target directory, I run `java -jar ./demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and the application run successfully.